"Disks" gnome-disk-utility - any way to add warnings for disk operations before they are implemented?
I might be asking for too much here.
I'd like to have warning messages pop up before I delete partitions or any other major disk operations using the disks utility. Is this possible?

You could ask the Gnome guys to add it but not here.

you have explored the hamburger menu I guess. If you delete a file (without deleting permanently) you can either, use Ctrl+Z to undo move to wastebasket or use the menu option to do so instead.

Almost everything that Gnome Disks does is dangerous. That's why it already has several layers of protection to prevent users from unintended folly.

IIRC gparted batches up operations and only executes them when you click a button for that. That was enough for me to have some leeway to fix any mistaken operations
